# React-redux component rerenders every time when and unconnected state changes in the store . How do I prevent it?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a component callled FileHeader. Everytime I resize a column in it, it dispatches an action to changes a state. This triggers a rerender.

**ListeHeader.js**

```
const ListHeader = props => {
const dispatch = useDispatch()
let headerRef = useRef(new Array())
const { header_ } = useSelector((state) => state.ui, shallowEqual)

 
const onResize = ( e, {event, node, size}) => {
   
  dispatch(changeHeaderWidth(node.id, size.width))
}


 return (
   <HeaderBody>
     {header_
       
       .map((header) => {
         const getRef = (element) => headerRef.current.push(element)
         return (
           <ResizableBox
             axis="x"
             width={header.width}
             height={20}
             key={header.id}
             handle={<DragHandle id={header.id} />}
             onResize={onResize}
             minConstraints={[50, 20]}
             maxConstraints={[300, 20]}
           >
             <Header
               key={header.id}
               width={header.width}
               handleDrag={handleDrag}
               onClick={handleSort(header.id)}
             >
               <HeaderText ref={getRef}>{header.name}</HeaderText>
             </Header>
           </ResizableBox>
         )
       })}
   </HeaderBody>
 ) 
}
```

This is my reducer

```
export default (state = initial_state, actions) => {
  switch (actions.type) {
     case consts.CHANGE_HEADER_WIDTH :  return {
       ...state,
       headerWidth: state.headerWidth.map((item) =>
         item.id === actions.payload.id ?  { ...item, width: actions.payload.neWidth} 
                  : item),
     } 
       
     break;
   
    default: return state;
  }
}
```

I'm not calling headerWidth state in my component it causes a rerender when it changes

Comment: Is maybe a parent component rerendering? If a parent rerenders in React, all children also rerender. That has nothing to do with Redux per se.

Comment: The parent and the other sibling components are not rerendering. I checked with react devtools... the rerendering correponds with the onResize event

Comment: Are there any changeHeaderWidth actions being dispatched you do not expect to? You can verify that using the Redux Devtools.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks)

> When passing a callback using dispatch to a child component, you may
> sometimes want to memoize it with useCallback. If the child component
> is trying to optimize render behavior using React.memo() or similar,
> this avoids unnecessary rendering of child components due to the
> changed callback reference.

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

export const CounterComponent = ({ value }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const incrementCounter = useCallback(
    () => dispatch({ type: 'increment-counter' }),
    [dispatch]
  )

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{value}</span>
      <MyIncrementButton onIncrement={incrementCounter} />
    </div>
  )
}

export const MyIncrementButton = React.memo(({ onIncrement }) => (
  <button onClick={onIncrement}>Increment counter</button>
))
```

Comment: I used useCallback but it is still rerendering